# Push array of object if data is same

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object

I have an some array of objects that looks like this:

```
const data = [
  { date: "04-08-2021", name: "bojes" },
  { date: "03-08-2021", name: "yolla" },
  { date: "02-08-2021", name: "rafika" },
  { date: "01-08-2021", name: "adit" },
  { date: "26-07-2021", name: "qor" },
  { date: "10-05-2021", name: "pandu" },
]
```

And an array of 7 days before current date that looks like this:

```
const dataCurretToLastWeek = [
  "29-07-2021",
  "30-07-2021",
  "01-08-2021",
  "02-08-2021",
  "03-08-2021",
  "04-08-2021",
  "05-08-2021",
]
```

And want to transform it into something like this:

```
const newData = [
  { date: "04-08-2021", name: "bojes" },
  { date: "03-08-2021", name: "yolla" },
  { date: "02-08-2021", name: "rafika" },
  { date: "01-08-2021", name: "adit" },
]
```

How can this be achieved?

Comment: What have you tried so far? It seems like you might want to look into the `filter` array method and the `includes` array method

Answer (score 5):

You can use `array#filter` and `array#includes` to do this:

[**`array#filter`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

> **MDN Web Docs:**
> The filter() method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.

[**`array#includes`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

> **MDN Web Docs:**
> The includes() method determines whether an array includes a certain value among its entries, returning true or false as appropriate.

**Full code:**

```js
const dataCurretToLastWeek = [
  "29-07-2021",
  "30-07-2021",
  "01-08-2021",
  "02-08-2021",
  "03-08-2021",
  "04-08-2021",
  "05-08-2021"
];

const data = [
  {'date': '04-08-2021','name':'bojes'},
  {'date': '03-08-2021','name':'yolla'},
  {'date': '02-08-2021','name':'rafika'},
  {'date': '01-08-2021','name':'adit'},
  {'date': '26-07-2021','name':'qor'},
  {'date': '10-05-2021','name':'pandu'}
];

const newData = data.filter(({date}) => dataCurretToLastWeek.includes(date))

console.log(newData)
```